# Php echo some text;

Tags: php, syntax

I was going through a php file and there I saw this line

```
echo PRO_PREVIEW_BUTTON;
```

and actually didn't even find this PRO_PREVIEW_BUTTON printed anywhere in htmlfile.

So what does it mean according to you???

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: find a line that's similar to this `define('PRO_PREVIEW_BUTTON', '');` either in this file or in one of the included ones.  You will see the defined value not the literal itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
echo PRO_PREVIEW_BUTTON;
```

This is surely a constant expression.

You can test it this way:

```
define('PRO_PREVIEW_BUTTON', 'Some value');
echo PRO_PREVIEW_BUTTON;
```

Constants do not need a $ (dollar sign) before it.